# Proper way to declare a "not set" enum value

Tags: c, enums, initialization

If using an enum for which you cannot alter the contents, e.g.,

```
typedef enum {
  sun=0,
  mon=1,
  tue=2,
  wed=3,
  thu=4,
  fri=5,
  sat=6,
} days;
```

Is there any way to safely have some code that looks like:

```
days day;

day = /*what goes here*/;

if (somecondition)
{
  day = sun;
}
else if (othercondition)
{
  day = mon;
}

if (day != /*what goes here*/)
{
  use(day);
}
```

Besides creating another sentinel that shows that day was set and without relying on knowing the contents of the days enum?

Answer (score 3):

In similar coding, I try to reserve the first enum (0) as the "NULL" value:

```
typedef enum { 
  nullday = 0,
  sun=1,
  mon=2,
  tue=3,
  wed=4,
  thu=5,
  fri=6, 
  sat=7,
} days;
```

That allows for a 'non-day' day:

```
days day;

day = nullday;

if (somecondition)
{
  day = sun;
}
else if (othercondition)
{
  day = mon;
}

if (day != nullday)
{
  use(day);
}
```

Another version of the code:

```
typedef enum {nullday=0, sun, mon,tue,wed,thu,fri,sat} days;

...

days day = nullday;

if (somecondition)
{
  day = sun;
}
else if (othercondition)
{
  day = mon;
}

if (day)
{
  use(day);
}
```

Comment: I'd have started with `-1` as "*undefined day*". Beware that programmers start counting at `0`. ;-)